# How to convert 24 hours to 12 hours in Excel

Tags: c#, excel

My problem is I want to convert my time in `DataGridView` into 12 hours format while I export it into Excel file.

This is my code:

```
Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel._Application app = new Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Application();
Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel._Workbook workbook = app.Workbooks.Add(Type.Missing);
Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel._Worksheet worksheet = null;

worksheet = workbook.Sheets["Sheet1"];
worksheet = workbook.ActiveSheet;
worksheet.Name = "Exported from gridview";
for (int i = 1; i < dataGridView1.Columns.Count + 1; i++)
{
    worksheet.Cells[1, i] = dataGridView1.Columns[i - 1].HeaderText;
}

for (int i = 0; i < dataGridView1.Rows.Count - 1; i++)
{
    (worksheet.Rows[i + 2 + ":" + i + 2, System.Reflection.Missing.Value] as Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Range).NumberFormat = "@";
    for (int j = 0; j < dataGridView1.Columns.Count; j++)
    {

        worksheet.Cells[i + 2, j + 1] = dataGridView1.Rows[i].Cells[j].Value.ToString();


       worksheet.Cells[i + 2, 3].NumberFormat = "h:mm AM/PM";
    }
}
var saveFileDialoge = new SaveFileDialog();
saveFileDialoge.FileName = "output";
saveFileDialoge.DefaultExt = ".xlsx";
if (saveFileDialoge.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK)
{
    workbook.SaveAs(saveFileDialoge.FileName, Type.Missing, Type.Missing, Type.Missing, Type.Missing, Type.Missing, Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.XlSaveAsAccessMode.xlExclusive, Type.Missing, Type.Missing, Type.Missing, Type.Missing, Type.Missing);
    app.Visible = true;
```

This is if I debug my codes:

[image: this is if i debug my codes]

This is if I export it in excel:

[image: this is if i export it in excel]

Comment: Why are you calling `Value.ToString()`? Pass `Value`, the `NumberFormat` will do the rest.

Comment: A time in Excel is just a plain number, floating-point if I remember correctly. So you actually do not want to change the value but the format of the respective cells in excel (which is basically what Sinatr is saying, too).

Comment: Dates and times in Excel are strongly-typed OADate values. In C# and interop, you should use `DateTime`, not a string.  And yes, their binary representation is a float. You change how they look by changing the cell's style to the one you want.

Comment: Another option is to *avoid* interop and use a library like Epplus to create a real Excel file from the input data with, eg `sheet.Cells.LoadFromDataTable`, `LoadFromCollection` or `LoadFromDataReader`.

Comment: BTW a DataGridView displays data, it's not the data itself, nor does it hold an accurate copy of that data. The code you used to load it may have converted dates to strings for example. It's easier to export the original data